# How to create a static class of integers?

Tags: c#, static, integer

First, an example, in Windows Forms I can call:

```
Color.Red;
```

And get a hash back. What I am looking for is to have an ErrorLevel class which has things like:

```
ErrorLevel.Warning
```

Where it simply returns an integer with a value of 0, 1, etc.

I have a good understanding of static classes, interfaces etc.

I'm not interested in alternatives on how to do this, like if some console class already has this functionality as I want to learn about this subject.

Also what it's called could help me with google searches/online tutorials.

Right now I'm messing around with this, but have no real idea what I'm doing.

```
internal class ErrorLevel
{
    public static ErrorLevel Error { get; }
    public static ErrorLevel Warning { get; }
    public static ErrorLevel Info { get; }
}
```

Comment: You can (and probably should) look at source code for the thing you want to emulate: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Color.cs,9103fd761ca562ae

Comment: @UnholySheep Wow, um thanks I can't believe I never knew that existed. I feel a little stupid now but I'm sure this will help me greatly. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class an `ErrorLevel` contains three `ErrorLevel`s.  What does each of those contain?  They would contain three `ErrorLevel`s.  Each of which contains three `ErrorLevel`s...  At no point is there ever an actual value.

At its simplest, it sounds like you're describing an `enum`:

```
public enum ErrorLevel
{
    Error,
    Warning,
    Info
}
```

But if you want something more custom like functionality you describe, then focus on what you've described:

> And get a hash back

So the property value is `string`.  If your properties should be strings, make them as such:

```
internal class ErrorLevel
{
    public static string Error { get; } = "Error";
    public static string Warning { get; } = "Warning";
    public static string Info { get; } = "Info";
}
```

Or even perhaps just constant values:

```
internal class ErrorLevel
{
    public const string Error = "Error";
    public const string Warning = "Warning";
    public const string Info = "Info";
}
```

Comment: This answers all my questions in detail, thanks a bunch - I'll mark it as so when the cooldown ends.

Comment: Or just use fields that are `const strings`:  `public const string Error = "Error";`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an [enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum)?

```
public enum ErrorLevel 
{ 
  Error, 
  Warning,
  Info
}
```

You can get the string using such a thing:

```
var level = ErrorLevel.Warning; // 1

string str = level.ToString();  // "Warning"
```

Of course, you can also use a static class having consts:

```
static public class ErrorLevel
{
  public const int Error = 0;
  public const int Warning = 1;
  public const int Info = 2;
}
```

But it seems like an enum is better for your purpose, unless you need more flexibility or need to change the values (no more consts):

```
static public class ErrorLevel
{
  static public int Error = 0;
  static public int Warning = 1;
  static public int Info = 2;
}
```